# Terraform "primary workGroup could not be created"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm  trying to execute query on my table In amazone  but i cant execute any query i had this  error msg :

```
Before you run your first query, you need to set up a query result location in Amazon S3.

Your query has the following error(s):

No output location provided. An output location is required either through the Workgroup result configuration setting or as an API input. (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: b6b9aa41-20af-4f4d-91f6-db997e226936)
```

So i'm trying to add   Workgroup but i have this problem

```
'Error: error creating Athena WorkGroup: InvalidRequestException: primary workGroup could not be created
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "c20801a0-3c13-48ba-b969-4e28aa5cbf86"
  },
  AthenaErrorCode: "INVALID_INPUT",
  Message_: "primary workGroup could not be created"
}
'
```

Mycode

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tony" {
  bucket = "tfouh"
}


resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "primary" {
  name       = "primary"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.tony]
  configuration {
    enforce_workgroup_configuration    = false
    publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true

    result_configuration {
      output_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.tony.bucket}/"

      encryption_configuration {
        encryption_option = "SSE_S3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

please if there are solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you **already have** `primary` work group. Thus, you can't create new one of the same name. Just create a work group with different name if you want:

```
 name       = "primary2"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Marcin suggested a valid approach, but what may be closer to what you are looking for would to to [import existing workgroup into the state](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/athena_workgroup#import):

```
terraform import aws_athena_workgroup.primary primary
```

[image]
Once the state knows about the already existing resource it can do the plan and apply possible changes.